# PHP connection to sharepoint database: MSSQL 2005 ODBC Driver or Webservices?

Tags: php, sql-server, web-services, sharepoint, odbc

I'm trying to connect a web portal coded in PHP to a Sharepoint database. I researched and there are 2 possible options to use: MSSQL 2005 OBDC Driver and Webservices.

Which of this 2 options is the better one, and why?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: SharePoint isn't a database

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy answer.  The answer is the web services because directly querying SharePoint's databases is not allowed from a supportability standpoint (reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_farnhill/2013/12/04/directly-querying-sharepoint-databases/)

To summarize some of the core arguments is that directly talking to the database (even if it is just reads) introduces unpredictable locking of database resources which will cause problems.  On top of this, the Content Database schema is not the best of my knowledge formally documented and of course subject to frequent changes.  If you've ever peered inside you'll see that it is quite complicated and thus difficult to come up with generic SQL to get the data you want.  The API (and therefore the web services) have done the hard work to give you a generic interface into SharePoint and to hide the complexity.

Lastly, if you are at all thinking about modifying SharePoint you are an absolute glutton for pain if you think about using direct SQL.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the correct answer? SharePoint isn't a database. The schema is undocumented and directly connecting to the database is *not* supported. What looks like a list in the UI is stored as a kind-of-EAV schema that needs extensive parsing to produce a record